# Where / when to use connection.close()

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anyone help me about the connection.Open() and close(). I'm not very sure about when to close and open the connection. The code that is giving me an error is added below.

If anyone who can give me a tip about this, I would appreciate it. Please feel free to edit my code showing where to close the connection in order for me to learn from it.

I am still a student. Thank you. =)

```
public class LoanDAL
{
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Oakhorizons"].ToString();
public LoanDAL()
{
    //
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here
    //
}
public DataTable getAllLoanInfoDT()
{
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
            cmd2.Connection = conn;
            // cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT loanUpdateDate FROM LoanPortfolio WHERE (custID LIKE 'OH00002') AND (loanType LIKE 'Personal Loan')";
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custID", "OH00002");
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loanType", "Personal Loan");
            conn.Open();
            DateTime loanUpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
            SqlDataReader myReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                loanUpdateDate = Convert.ToDateTime(myReader[0]); 
                break; 
            }

            DateTime currDateTime = DateTime.Now;

            int loanToBeAdded = (((currDateTime.Year - loanUpdateDate.Year) * 12) + currDateTime.Month - loanUpdateDate.Month) * 500;
            if (loanToBeAdded > 0)
            {
                String sql = "UPDATE LoanPortfolio SET loanPaid = loanPaid + " + loanToBeAdded.ToString() + ", LastUpdatedLoanPaidDate = " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
                sql += " WHERE (loanType LIKE 'Personal Loan') AND (custID LIKE 'OH00002')";
                cmd2.Connection = conn;
                cmd2.CommandText = sql;
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            conn.Close();
            using (SqlDataAdapter dAd = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM LoanPortfolio where custID like 'OH00002'", conn))
            {
                DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
                dAd.Fill(dTable);
                return dTable;
            }

        }

}

//Returning a DataSet which contains all the information in the Player Table
public DataSet getAllLoanInfoDS()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {

        using (SqlDataAdapter dAd = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM LoanPortfolio where custID like 'OH00002", conn))
        {
            DataSet myDS = new DataSet();
            dAd.Fill(myDS);
            return myDS;
        }



    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why dont add a 'finally' block and close the connection after every method. Then reopen the connection at the beginning of every method. Rule of thumb: As long as you need Data from your Sqlserver you need an open connection. One connection can only handle one query until it become closed and reopend.

Comment: what is the exception you get?

Comment: where are you opening connection in `getAllLoanInfoDS()` ?

Comment: Lets say connection is a door to the room. Room stores data. And you have basket(aka datatable) and you can fill it with data. So what you need to do to take data from room and fill the basket? Simply open door, fill basket with data, close door. And bum you have basket with data ;)

Comment: I got this error. "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first"

Comment: I'm so sad, check your solution on sqlinjection.

Comment: sqlinjection? what is that? how to check solution?

Comment: You need to open connection just before execution and close it after execute reader for **dataadapter** no need to open or close connection explicitly ,Dataadapter manages connection state automatically .Look at your error than look at your code you will get answer :: You opened connection for ExecuteDatareader and did not closed it before calling Update method .Why don't just close connection after Execute Datareader and open again for ExecuteNonQuery and close immediately after that . Catch exception nd close connection in case of exception also to free your resources .

Comment: Your connection string needs to have **"MultipleActiveResultSets=True"** added to it.If you are using multiple command like you are having two commands in a single connection ,Either enable **"MultipleActiveResultSets=True"** in your connection string or ,Open and close after every transaction with server (Single command per connection).

Comment: where should I put that "MultipleActiveResultSets=True" ???

Comment: Because you are not releasing your connection after Execute reader command and it holds on to your connection , To allow multiple commands in a single connection you need to use **MultipleActiveResultSets=True"** (Single connection means you are not closing connection and same connection continues).But i will prefer if you close your connection in your code after Executereader and open it again for ExecuteNonQuery and close it after command.

Answer (score 2):

you don't have close the connection explicitly since you're having using {} block with sqlconnection object. The connection will automatically get closed.

second if you want to close the connection explicitly then close it once all your db operations are finished.

for e.g. close it when your adapter fill operation is finished.

```
....
....
....
using (SqlDataAdapter dAd = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM LoanPortfolio where custID like 'OH00002'", conn))
                {
                    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
                    dAd.Fill(dTable);
                    conn.Close();
                    return dTable;
                }
```

Comment: if connection is not already opened then .Fill() will open it, use it and close it. but it's not a restriction you can explicitly open/close the connection when you're doing multiple db operations and that would lead to enhance the performance.

Answer (score 0):

This section:

```
conn.Close();
using (SqlDataAdapter dAd = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM LoanPortfolio where custID like 'OH00002'", conn))
{
    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
    dAd.Fill(dTable);
    return dTable;
}
```

You are re-using the same connection after closing it. Re-open and re-use. Or don't close at all as you are still in the same `using` block.

**Update**: MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z(v=vs.100).aspx

> The Fill method implicitly opens the Connection that the DataAdapter
>   is using if it finds that the connection is not already open. If Fill
>   opened the connection, it will also close the connection when Fill is
>   finished.

So, in the above section "conn.close()" shouldn't matter, "Fill" will open the connection and close it.

The `using` block will dispose off the connection once done with it. So, explicitly closing a connection is not required.

Comment: so what is the fix? or what you suggesting?

Comment: I overlooked the SqlAdapter. Answer updated. Certainly need more info from OP about where exactly is he getting an exception.

Comment: He is using single connection for EXECUTEReader and for Update also , Check his code you will see he is not releasing connection and Readers hold on to connection object . You can use **MultipleActiveResultSets=True"** in your connection string so that your connection allows multiple commands but when using MultipleActiveResultSets=True" you have to take care of which command you are using and how , Consider you use **MultipleActiveResultSets=True"** but in your method you are updating and selecting data , so it may possible you will get wrong data .

Answer (score 0):

Sql dataAdapter itself manages connection .it opens and closes after fill command , However using ExecuteReader or ExecuteNonQuery explicitly requires connection to open and close, you can open conection just before executing nonquery and executereader command , 
 How ever one more scenario could be if your code faces an error and code does not reach to **conn.close();** command .

```
   public class LoanDAL
{
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Oakhorizons"].ToString();
public LoanDAL()
{
    //
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here
    //
}
public DataTable getAllLoanInfoDT()
{
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
            cmd2.Connection = conn;
            // cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT loanUpdateDate FROM LoanPortfolio WHERE (custID LIKE 'OH00002') AND (loanType LIKE 'Personal Loan')";
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custID", "OH00002");
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loanType", "Personal Loan");

            DateTime loanUpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
            try
            {
             conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader myReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                loanUpdateDate = Convert.ToDateTime(myReader[0]); 
                break; 
            }
               conn.Close();   
            DateTime currDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            }
            Catch(Exception Ex)
            {//Close connection in case of any exception .
              conn.Close();
            }
            int loanToBeAdded = (((currDateTime.Year - loanUpdateDate.Year) * 12) + currDateTime.Month - loanUpdateDate.Month) * 500;
            if (loanToBeAdded > 0)
            {
               try
               {
                String sql = "UPDATE LoanPortfolio SET loanPaid = loanPaid + " + loanToBeAdded.ToString() + ", LastUpdatedLoanPaidDate = " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
                sql += " WHERE (loanType LIKE 'Personal Loan') AND (custID LIKE 'OH00002')";
                cmd2.Connection = conn;
                cmd2.CommandText = sql;
                 conn.Open();
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                }
                Catch(Exception Ex)
                 {
                 //Close connection in case of exception .
                  Conn.close()
                  throw Ex;
                 }
            }            
            using (SqlDataAdapter dAd = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM LoanPortfolio where custID like 'OH00002'", conn))
            {
                DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
                dAd.Fill(dTable);
                return dTable;
            }

        }

}

//Returning a DataSet which contains all the information in the Player Table
public DataSet getAllLoanInfoDS()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {

        using (SqlDataAdapter dAd = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM LoanPortfolio where custID like 'OH00002", conn))
        {
            DataSet myDS = new DataSet();
            dAd.Fill(myDS);
            return myDS;
        }



    }
}
}
```

**Your connection string needs to have "MultipleActiveResultSets=True" added to it.If you are using multiple command like you are having two commands in a single connection ,Either enable "MultipleActiveResultSets=True" in your connection string or ,Open and close after every transaction with server (Single command per connection).**